# New measure constructed out of supremum of old measure

Tags: measure-theory

This is a homework exercise. Let  $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu_1)$ be a measure space. Define for $A\in\mathcal{A}$
$$
\mu_2(A) = \sup \;\{\mu_1(B):B\in\mathcal{A},B\subset A, \mu_1(B) < \infty \}.
$$
Show that $\mu_2$ is a measure.

The first problem is that I fail to see why
$$
\mu_2(A \cup B) = \mu_2(A) + \mu_2(B)
$$
for $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$. The left side is given by
$$
\mu_2(A \cup B) = \sup \;\{\mu_1(D):D\in\mathcal{A},D\subset A \cup B, \mu_1(D) < \infty \}.
$$
I don't see why this is equal to
$$
\mu_2(A) + \mu_2(B) = \sup \;\{\mu_1(D):D\in\mathcal{A},D\subset A, \mu_1(D) < \infty \} \\
+ \sup \;\{\mu_1(D):D\in\mathcal{A},D\subset B, \mu_1(D) < \infty \}.
$$

Comment: I fail to see why $\mu_2(A) \ne \mu_1(A)$.

Comment: I think $\mu_1 = \mu_2$.

Comment: If $\mu_1(A)=\infty$ then $\mu_2(A)$ doesn't have to be $\infty$, right?

Comment: @simon Using $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu_1$ I think it has to be, or do you force $B$ to be a proper subset ($B \subsetneq A$)? In wich case $\mu_2$ is not a measure unless $\mathcal A$ contains no one-point sets...

Comment: No $B$ doesn't have to be a proper subset. How do I use the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu_1$?

Comment: I think $ \mu_1 $ is not necessarily equal to $ \mu_2 $. Take e.g. $ X = \{ 0,1 \}, \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{P}(X) $ and define $ \mu_1 $ to be $ \mu_1(0) = 0, \mu_1(1) = \infty $. Then you get that $ \mu_2(1) = \mu_1(\emptyset) = 0 \neq \mu_1(2) $.

Comment: @simon Nevermind, I oversaw the constraint $\mu_1(B) < \infty$ wich may lead to a different result if $\mu_1(A) = \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $A\cup B \supset D\in \mathcal A$ and $A\cap B = \emptyset$ so we can write
$$D = D_A \dot\cup D_B$$
Where $D_A \subset A$ and $D_B \subset B$. Since $\mu_1(D) < \infty, \mu_1(D_A)$ and $\mu_1(D_B)$ are finite as well, so
$$D_A \in \{S\in\mathcal A, S\subset A, \mu_1(S)<\infty\} =: S_A$$
And $D_B\in S_B$. Similarly for each $E_A\in S_A$ and $E_B\in S_B$, $E_A \cup E_B \in S_{A\cup B}$, so
$$S_{A\cup B} = \bigcup S_A \times S_B = \{ D_A \dot\cup D_B\; |\; D_A \in S_A, D_B \in S_B\} \tag{$\ast$}$$
This means by additivity of $\mu_1$
$$\begin{align*}
\mu_2(A\cup B) & = \sup_{D\in S_{A\cup B}} \mu_1(D) \\
& \stackrel{(\ast)}= \sup_{D_A \in S_A, D_B \in S_B} \mu_1(D_A \cup D_B) = \sup_{D_A\in S_A, D_B\in S_B} \mu_1(D_A) + \mu_2(D_B)\\
& = \sup_{D_A\in S_A} \mu_1(D_A) + \sup_{D_B\in S_B} \mu_1(D_B) = \mu_2(A) + \mu_2(B)
\end{align*}$$